# NSTimer nonstop memory increasing - iOS bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, sdk

I'm figuring out memory issues with an iPad app using instruments - looking at the overall allocated bytes.  My NSTimer causes the bytes to constantly increase, while commenting it out causes memory usage to remain static.

From viewDidLoad of my view controller:

```
tickTime = 1.0 / 30.0;
tickTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:tickTime target: self selector:@selector(update2) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

And the method update2:

```
- (void) update2 {

}
```

As you can see there is nothing done in the method whatsoever - yet the memory usage of the app constantly grows.  If I comment out the line where I setup the timer, the memory usage remains the same.

Is this a bug in the iOS SDK?  Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what this timer is for?  Do you need it to update that frequently?  Also, what type of variable is `tickTime`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pebkac issue - I was studying the "Overall Bytes" in Instruments, which is a measure of all memory the app has ever used, rather than a measure of current memory usage.

I'm still curious how to measure the app's current total memory usage - as "Live Bytes" is around 1.5mb - even with at least 20mb of .pngs loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Does memory use drop if you do something via the UI?  I.e. if you tap a button or something?

What objects are hanging about that shouldn't?  Instruments gives a lot more information than just that your heap is growing.

In general, having a timer that ticks at 1/30th of a second interval is to be avoided.

- if it is on the main thread, it'll make your app's responsiveness very choppy (at best) or totally unresponsive
- if you are trying to do animation, use Core Animation (or one of the various Open GL patterns)
- it'll eat battery life.

Comment: I said "to be avoided", not "totally broken".  Any kind of polling or rapid fire mechanism is to be avoided, if at all possible.  Your app will perform better & consume less power if you let the system take care of tight periodic tasks as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the timer may be "firing" to fast for the iPhone to process. I had this same problem and had to slow the timer down.