# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval increase the memory allocate

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nstimer

When I use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method of `NSTimer` with Repeat "YES" every time the `@selector` called will cause the memory increasing a little

The application in running in ARC mode~

```
- (void)d{
    NSLog(@"%f -- %f",0.0f , 0.0f);
}


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(d) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Can you give us more specifics about the magnitude of the memory usage?  Is it consequential?

Comment: @NSBum every time it's about 0.01M

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4432918/529363)